# Uppercase tags in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jqgrid-asp.net

I have an HTML manipulation issue that manifests itself only in IE8.

I had recently written some javascript that analysed a tag and did something depending on what it was.

The piece of code assumed the tag was in lowercase.

```
if(value.indexOf('<input') == -1)
```

This failed under IE8 and I have to fix it.

Now I could and a second check as follows:

```
if(value.indexOf('<input') == -1 && value.indexOf('<INPUT') == -1)
```

This will catch both possibilities, but seems awfully messy.

Is there a better way to deal with this situation? 
Could JQuery deal with this?

"value" is an html string passed to my javascript function from JQGrid. Using IE8 the string is uppercase, using IE9, FF, Chrome, it is lowercase.

Comment: I'm intrigued, under what circumstances does IE chagne the casing of your HTML or is this only if you tell IE to generate code itself?

Comment: @Chris: well, for one thing we don't know how `value` is retreived, but whenever you're getting a DOM node you're just working with an internal representation of the document, that is only loosely related to the code you wrote to generate that document. Most browsers would report an `innerHTML`, say, as lowercase, regardless of the casing you used to create the document, although IE9 yields all uppercase, if you're running it in quirks mode.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: Yeah, I see what you mean about the DOM. I think that if value is a part of the dom being converted to a string before testing for the presence of specific elements then something is going wrong earlier than the part where we are looking for strings. ;-)

Comment: I realise my first sentence is quite misleading. Value is being returned by JQGrid. In IE9, FF, Chrome etc, it comes back lowercase, in IE8 it comes back upper case. I did a google search and saw a few people mentioning but I'm not sure the exact reason.

Comment: I've updated the question now to make it clearer....hopefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your situation obviously you could also use jquery `.is()` function to test for an element http://api.jquery.com/is/

for instance

```
$target.is("input")
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

`if(value.toLowerCase().indexOf('<input') == -1)`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if(value.toLowerCase().indexOf('<input') == -1) { ... }
```

or

```
if(!/\<input/i.test(value)) { ... }
```

The latter being a regular expression with the ignore case flag set.